# How to debug MVC web app with rest api controller backend?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've created an mvc asp.net core solution with the following structure:

1. REST API controller on the back-end
2. ASP.NET MVC Framework on the front-end. The frontend project connects to the backend api via axios - i.e. it calls the rest controllers from the backend project from the javascript code.

The way I've been running this so far in Visual Studio is like this:

1. Select the API project and click start without debugging
2. Then set the front-end project to the startup project click the green arrow that starts it running.

All the internals of the project work fine. However, I can't seem to debug the project. When I set breakpoints in the API, and run just the API project, the breakpoints appear as normal - little filled in red dots.

But as soon as I start up the frontend project, those backend breakpoints switch to hollow circles with a message that "this break point will not be hit... symbols not loaded".

How do I debug the back-end while running the front end?

Comment: Clarification: You have an ASP.NET MVC application that talks to an ASP.NET Web API project? Or do you have a JavaScript based MVC project that talks to an API?

Comment: Are you running in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: Edited for clarity, thanks. Running in debug mode.

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much. My apologies for posting a duplicate: I definitely spent several hours digging around stack overflow before posting!